# Weaker conjectures to prove in order to arrive at P =/= NP

Tags: proof-techniques, p-vs-np

We know we have a long way to go before we come to a proof of ***P*** $\neq$ ***NP***. We also know that this road is studded with minor conjectures that will have to be proved/disproved in order to arrive at the much sought-after truth.

My question is the following: if tomorrow a proof of ***P*** $\neq$ ***NP*** would appear, what would be all the *CS* open problems that such a proof would solve?

Comment: Many results in complexity theory are conditional on P≠NP.

Comment: For results and conjectures that are weaker than P≠NP, and are suspected to be on the road to prove P≠NP, see Section 6 in Scott Aaronson's P vs NP survey https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf.